# Let $G = \mathbb{Z}_{512} \times \mathbb{Z}_{1729}$ and let $H = <([0],[1])>$. Show that $G/H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{512}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, normal-subgroups, direct-product

Let $G = \mathbb{Z}_{512} \times \mathbb{Z}_{1729}$ and let $H$ be the subgroup generated by $([0],[1])$. Show that $G/H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{512}$.

This is using direct products.

First I tried to get $H$

$H = \{([0],[1])\}$ Since $\forall [a] \in \mathbb{Z}_n [a][0] = [a0]=[0]$ and  $[a][1] = [a]$, so $([0],[1])^n = ([0],[1]) \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

$G/H = \{g_1H, g_2H,... \} = \{g_1\{([0],[1])\}, g_2\{([0],[1])\}, ...\}$

For an arbitrary $([a],[b])$ then $([a],[b])([0],[1])=([0],[b])$

Then $G/H = \{\{([0],[b])\} : [b] \in \mathbb{Z}_{1729}\}$

Define $\phi:G/H \to \mathbb{Z}_{512} : \phi(\{[0],[b])\}) = [b]$

I am stuck. What I am seeing is that it is isomorphic to $Z_{1729}$. What am I doing wrong or how can I "truncate" the $[b]$ values to $\mathbb{Z}_{512}$?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what your group is. What are its elements? What is the operation?

Comment: The problem does not indicate specifically what operation each individual group has. So I am assuming it is multiplication on $\mathbb{Z}_n$. $G$ is the direct product of $\mathbb{Z}_{512}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{1729}$, so $G \ni ([a],[b])([c],[d]) = ([a][c], [b][d])$ where the first and second terms in the ordered pair use the operation of the first and second sets in the direct product $G$ respectively.

Comment: The operation is modular addition because $\mathbb Z_n$ is not group under multiplication since $[0]$ has no inverse.

Comment: Ok, this changed everything. Thank you! I think I got it now! @lhf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Prove that the map $\mathbb{Z}_{512} \times \mathbb{Z}_{1729} \to \mathbb{Z}_{512}$ given by $(x,y) \mapsto x$ is surjective. Find its kernel.

Comment: I know it is some projection, but wouldn't that map give me only $[0]$?

Comment: @TheBosco, where does $([1],[0])$ maps to?

Comment: $[1]$ but I need a map from $G/H$ not $G$.